# What did Martin Luther King mean by "In the end we will remember not the words of our enemies, but the silence of our friends"?

Tags: figurative-language, proverbs

I was reading a pamphlet titled **'The Wise saying'** then saw this saying:

> "In the end we will remember not the words of our enemies, but the **silence** of our friends." By Martin Luther King

What could he possibly mean?

I'm thinking that 'silence' here refers to the death of friends of King.

Comment: What is your problem with this?  *We (the African Americans people) will remember "that some of our 'friends' were silent (in the time of the civil rights campaigns)" rather than "the things that our enemies said about us"*.  The meaning seems very straightforward, with no difficult words or grammar!  So can you explain why this seems difficult for you?

Comment: How well do you know the context of the (ongoing) struggle for civil rights in  America?

Comment: James K, I seek knowledge not argument.

Comment: I'm not arguing.  I just can't answer your question because it is not clear to me what you need to be explained.  There is no figurative language in this quote, except perhaps the use of "silence" to mean "not speaking out"

Comment: I only needed clarification on the statement, because I don't understand it. And you're asking me about civil rights.

Comment: Okay.  I'll assume you know all the context and you are only asking about the figurative use of langauge.

Comment: King meant that (had he lived) he would remember the lack of support from those he hoped would give it, more than the opposition from where it was expected. A similar sentiment could be "It was what my supposed friend *didn't* say, that was revealing."

Comment: James K, now that you understand, would you please change your vote?

Comment: I haven't voted.

Answer (score 7):

Dr. King's most famous literary work is his *Letter from a Birmingham Jail*, written while he was imprisoned after a protest in April 1963.  In it, he criticizes fellow clergy who supported civil rights, but wanted to wait until it could be accomplished without civil disobedience or widespread unrest.

> ...When I was suddenly catapulted into the leadership of the bus protest in Montgomery, Alabama, a few years ago, I felt we would be supported by the white church. I felt that the white ministers, priests and rabbis of the South would be among our strongest allies. Instead, some have been outright opponents, refusing to understand the freedom movement and misrepresenting its leaders; *all too many others have been more cautious than courageous and have remained silent behind the anesthetizing security of stained glass windows*...

In both your quote and in the Letter, King is expressing the idea that it doesn't surprise us when our enemies lash out at us.  That's naturally what an enemy will do.  However, it is a shocking betrayal when a "friend" is not even willing to speak up to defend you.

Answer (score 5):

The only figurative language is the word "silence". "Silence" can mean "The act of refraining from speaking." or figuratively "The act of refraining from making any comment in speech, or written form.

King divides the American people into three groups:  "We" = African Americans.  "Our enemies" (Those people who oppose civil rights) and "Our friends" (Those people who support civil rights).  And he says that "We" will remember the *silence* of our friends.  "We" will remember when our friends did not say that they supported us, but instead allowed "our enemies" to attack us, and did not say anything.

I do not think this refers to the death of King's friends.

Comment: I was thinking that 'silence' here refers to the death of friends of King.

Comment: I've added that to the question.  When I asked  "What is your problem with this?" you could have answered "I was thinking that 'silence' here refers to the death of friends of King."

Answer (score 0):

"In the end we will remember not the words of our enemies, but the silence of our friends."

It could easily be seen as a threat.

Saying that, unless you believe and support what we believe, and do and say what we do and say, we will remember who you are and will make you pay for it later.

Comment: Is your interpretation really that the line promises retribution to those who don't support the movement?

Comment: I don't have 'an interpretation'.  I am looking for persuasive discussion in the interests of solidifying my interpretation.  I offered a possible take on the words of the sentence under discussion.  

For example;  read the sentence as though it were being softly and intently spoken by a Don Corleone -esque figure as he glared at someone.